# Where is the identifier of the struct?

Tags: parsing, rust, syntax, macros

https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.DataStruct.html:

```rust
pub struct DataStruct {
    pub struct_token: Struct,
    pub fields: Fields,
    pub semi_token: Option<Semi>,
}
```

Why is the identifier of the defined struct (`pub ident: Ident,`) missing?

Parsing `struct X { ... }`, how do I find `X`?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [`DeriveInput`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.DeriveInput.html) again.

Answer (score 1):

It's in [`DeriveInput`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.DeriveInput.html), because it is shared to structs and enums and unions:

```rust
pub struct DeriveInput {
    pub attrs: Vec<Attribute>,
    pub vis: Visibility,
    pub ident: Ident,
    pub generics: Generics,
    pub data: Data,
}
```